# How do I create a task scheduler to restart a software service in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service, task-scheduler

I have a pesky software service that fails every few weeks. It has two components. Service A and Service B. Service B gets in a weird state and stops accepting connections from Service A. The only way out is to restart both services manually, or reboot the server.

I would like to schedule a service restart for A and B on a regular basis. Say every 24 hours. How to go about it?

Comment: Scheduled task to launch a script?  `sc stop servicename` and `sc start servicename`  No?

Comment: Or run it locally,    _Net stop "serviceA" && Net start "serviceB"_ ; but I think the important part is, having to stop and restart a service is not a great solution for anything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I ended up creating a batch file containing the proper restart sequence with timeouts. Timeouts were necessary because of the dependencies between the services. I scheduled it to run as admin every night at 4AM using the task scheduler.

```
net stop "Service B"
net stop "Service A"
timeout /T 10
net start "Service B"
timeout /T 10
net start "Service A"
```

It's not ideal, but it will do for this scenario — a remote desktop deployment with less than 10 users.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a bat file, which can become corrupt or missing, you can create a scheduled task with **multiple** actions. One action to stop the service, and another one to restart the service. Both executed with the `NET` command. Give them a STOP and START argument, followed by the service name.

```
NET STOP "Service A" 
NET START "Service A"
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36309450/4746087) a post on StackOverflow explaining how.

Answer (score 2):

**Net Stop "ServiceName" && Net Start "ServiceName"**

And you can chain together && for Stop/Start ServiceB

**Net Stop "ServiceA" && Net Start "ServiceA" && Net Stop "ServiceB" && Net Start "ServiceB"**

Answer (score 0):

You can make a bat file and inside the bat try something like this:

net stop {serviceName} & net start {serviceName}

and use the bat file as a program for a scheduled task.

Comment: You need two ampersands in the string above.